# Spring Security - Authentication issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on a web application & have opted to use spring Security. The idea is for the user to be authenticated to see the Home Page, if the user is not authenticated they are redirected to the login page. This login page also displays a link to a registration form, This part is working correctly.

However, I have encountered an issue when attempting to allow users to sign up via the registration link. The  link to the registration form cannot be accessed if the user if not authenticated ("showRegistrationForm")

Can anyone provide insight to why this is occuring? I have Included the code snippet from my SecurityConfig below

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    //Restrict Access based on the Intercepted Servlet Request 

    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/register").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
    .antMatchers("/showForm/**").hasAnyRole("EMPLOYEE","MANAGER", "ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/save/**").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/delete/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .and()
    .formLogin()
// Show the custom form created for the below request mappings
        .loginPage("/showSonyaLoginPage")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
// No need to be logged in to see the login page
        .permitAll()
    .and()
// No need to be logged in to see the logout button.
    .logout().permitAll()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");    
}
```

Comment: It looks like something to do with action triggered on registration. Can you check what is the action triggered after registration?

Comment: Hi Amidala, I have added the registration code to the original post.

Comment: what is the view mapped to **registration-confirmation**? (Assuming you are using spring-mvc)

Comment: registration-confirmation displays a basic 'registration-successful' page and a link to return the user to login. A user can log in successfully if they enter their username & password and it will take them to the 'Home page'

Comment: I guess I want to remove authentication from the 'Registration page' and allow anyone to see it , however .permiteall() does not seem to be doing the job

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183129/discussion-between-amidala-siva-kumar-and-orangeflavour).

Comment: The antMatchers is configured to "/showRegistrationForm/" whereas postMapping points to " @PostMapping("/processRegistrationForm"). Dont you think that should be same?

Comment: You should call permitAll before calling `authenticated()` method

Comment: Hi  Subhasish Bhattacharjee, thank you for responding. I do agree they should be the same & have since added this to the antMatchers however sadly this would not stop the user from seeing the form only posting it :(

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like below:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    // Restrict Access based on the Intercepted Servlet Request 

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/showRegistrationForm/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
        .antMatchers("/resources/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/showForm/**").hasAnyRole("EMPLOYEE","MANAGER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/save/**").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/delete/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
    // Show the custom form created for the below request mappings
            .loginPage("/showSonyaLoginPage")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
    // No need to be logged in to see the login page
            .permitAll()
        .and()
    // No need to be logged in to see the logout button.
        .logout().permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");    
}
```

Moved down the below code:

```
anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Comment: Hey mate, I tried the code you provided & sadly it produces the same result. Thank you for trying :)